# Bitnami zookeeper is opening inbound security for Follower and Leader ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-zookeeper, amazon-elb, bitnami

I have deployed the latest bitnami-zookeeper helm chart (https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/zookeeper/11.1.6) in AWS , it's working fine as per the expectation. I have just installed it with default values.

Now, I have doubts when I am checking the security-group and load-balancer I can see the inbound rules also added for ports 2888 and 3888.  Is that expected? As per my understanding, only 2181 ports should open for any client connection. Please help me to understand this security-related doubts.

Below are some screenshots for reference.

[image]

[image]

Also, I can see "ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: yes", how to disable this using the above chart version?